# Calling function on a nested Objects property?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, in the second object I have nested property of 'request.createdAt'. My issue is how to iterate over this array, in order to reach this property, and parse the date to the same format as seen in the first object.

My last attempt was unsuccessful (returns an array of undefined) and very verbose, but I can't think of a better way.

```
arr.map((e) => e.request?.createdAt).filter(item => item).map((x) =>  e?.request ?  e.request.createdAt = Date.parse(x) : null)
```

Any tips would be appreciated

```
const arr = [{
    "id": 6533118084380,
    "public": true,
    "attachments": [],
    "via": {
        "channel": "email",
        "source": {
            "from": {
                "address": "testemail@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "createdAt": 1667804231000,
},
{
    "caseFileSlug": "11111111",
    "request": {
        "id": 1,
        "storyParams": {
            "preference": "no_backstory"
        },
        "requestComputed": {
            "minAmount": 137,
        },
        "storyParams": {
            "numberOfPeople": 5
        },
        "createdAt": "2022-11-09 17:26:51 UTC"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Your first map would return the createdAt string, unclear how you would think that you would be able to loop over that array of strings and get the request object.

Comment: What is the output you expect? An array of two date objects? Or do you want the original format with just the date converted?

Comment: Will `createdAt` always be in either the top level or inside an object called `request`?

Comment: @epascarello Noted. I'm looking for the objects to be returned in their entirety, but with the createdAt property parsed.

Comment: @Samathingamajig The array is a combo of two different sources, one source (rep'd by the second element) will always provide 'createdAt' as a child property of the Request object. The structure of both objects won't change

Comment: So map is entirely the wrong thing to use, you just loop over the object and if it has the property, overwrite it.

Comment: If you changed the first map to a filter that would be a good step, eliminating anything without request or request.createdAt. Then map to a new object containing the parsed date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map is for making an array with new content. You just need one loop and overwrite the property if it exists.

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": 6533118084380,
    "public": true,
    "attachments": [],
    "via": {
        "channel": "email",
        "source": {
            "from": {
                "address": "testemail@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "createdAt": 1667804231000,
},
{
    "caseFileSlug": "11111111",
    "request": {
        "id": 1,
        "storyParams": {
            "preference": "no_backstory"
        },
        "requestComputed": {
            "minAmount": 137,
        },
        "storyParams": {
            "numberOfPeople": 5
        },
        "createdAt": "2022-11-09 17:26:51 UTC"
    }
}]

arr.forEach((record) => {
  if (record?.request?.createdAt) {
    record.request.createdAt = (new Date(record.request.createdAt)).getTime();
  }
})

console.log(arr);
```

If there is a change it might be a number, you can add a type check.